# Crack on basement wall/foundation wall

Tags: walls, basement, foundation, crack

I noticed a crack on our basement wall or foundation wall (not sure what to call it). Our house is fairly new, built on mid 2017. We have a finished basement so there's no way to check the crack from inside unless I remove the basement interior wall. Is this something we should be worried about? Should we get a professional to check this or at least patch it if it's not a serious damage? Thanks in advance for any inputs! [image: crack on wall]

Answer (score 1):

That is not a problem and quite common. I would put a tape measure in the photo and take a photo then check it in a year, no change no big deal. Large change then con aging the builder may be a good idea. Also keep an eye on the earth below if the ground is going away (sink hole or settling) their may be a larger issue but small cracks are quite common.

Comment: I wish someone would do a study to learn the percentage of buildings that do or don't have foundation cracks. I would bet that the buildings without any cracks are in the minority.

Comment: I was taught many decades ago that there are 2 kinds of concrete. That that has cracks and the other will have cracks. Concrete continues to cure and get harder as it ages so if it did not crack to start with give it 10+ years. So yes the ones with no cracks are in the minority.